# Umbraco NiceUrl Alternative

Tags: umbraco

I'm in the process of migrating our old website from one CMS into Umbraco. However, I was just curious as to whether there was an out of the box alternative way of accessing pages. It looks like pages have their NiceUrl, however I was wondering if there was a way to access pages by specifying their page id in the querystring i.e. something like default.aspx?page=123.

I only ask as this is something we can achieve in our current CMS and it would make the migration a bit simpler.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access pages by simply using their ID as the page name ...

> http://example.com/**<nodeId>**.aspx
>   http://example.com/**<nodeId>**
>   http://example.com/**<nodeId>**/
>   
>   *The last one seems to work for at least Umbraco v6, but not earlier versions of v4, regardless of what you have `umbracoUseDirectoryUrls` set to in the `web.config`.*

... so for instance ...

> http://example.com/123.aspx
>   http://example.com/123
>   http://example.com/123/

... would all work, no matter how deep the node in question is within the content tree.

Comment: Thanks Goran, that's exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated.